# Can an iOS App's system settings be configured via Enterprise Distribution?

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution, enterprise

Apple's [Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf) says that apps distributed internally to an organization can be accompanied by a "Configuration Profile" that changes certain system settings (like VPN or wifi preferences).  Can the same system be used to distribute custom settings (as defined in the system wide "settings" application) for the enterprise application itself?

Comment: +1 for good question - hoping for an answer....

Answer (score 2):

Not externally pushed upon the app.

The way I would implement it is that the app checks in with the enterprise server upon launch and gets any app settings that way. A simple REST exchange should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html

After reading the documention it should be techically possible to implement but it looks like this feature is not available (yet).